# Concatenate two php variables in an sql query

Tags: php, mysql

So I have an sql query where I would like to query the database using the LIKE operator and the underscore wildcard where the first and last letter of a string are used to construct a pattern. I store the letters of a string in two php variables - $first(representing the first letter) and $last(representing the last letter) and from there they are used in the query. I have tried many different ways to get the query to work and so far I haven't had any success. Could you please look at my code and point out an error and/or suggest a correction. Any help will be appreciated.

```
$query2 = "SELECT name, description, subcategory, image, price FROM baby_products WHERE name LIKE '".$first."'+'_'+'".$last."'";
```

Comment: If I correctly understand you're missing the `CONCAT` function in the [MySQL Sting functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)

Comment: Or you can simply write `"SELECT name, description, subcategory, image, price FROM baby_products WHERE name LIKE '".$first.'_'.$last."'"`

Comment: I tried both methods plus Uchicha's method. They all worked. Thank you

Comment: You are spoiled for choice! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it out as

```
$query2 = "SELECT name, description, subcategory, image, price FROM 
baby_products WHERE name LIKE '%{$first}%' OR '%{$last}%'";
```